# How to set state of other component inside an axios get method in react?

Tags: reactjs, class, get, axios

I'm using class-based components in react. I have few components named as follows: `Blogs, BlogsClient, BlogCard.` When `Blogs` mounts I make a call to a function inside `BlogClient` named as `getBlogContent` to fetch me data using `axios`.

```
setBlogs = (blogs) => {
    this.setState({ "blogs": blogs });
}

componentDidMount() {
    getBlogContent(this.setBlogs);
}
```

where getBlogContent is:

```
let getBlogContent = (setBlogs) => {
store.set('loaded', false);
axios.get(ADMIN_URL + '/getAllBlogs')
    .then(response => {
        store.set('loaded', true);
        setBlogs(response.data.Response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        store.set('loaded', true);
        store.set('errorMessage', error);
    })
}
```

I'm able to fetch data and update my state properly. But If there comes any error inside `Blogs` or `BlogCard`(which is called inside `Blogs`) it goes inside the catch of `getBlogContent` whereas it should be only responsible for catching Axios error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do these errors occur on mounting or during an update? What does your browser's network console say?

Comment: During mounting. The network console says that the data is being fetched properly with status 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it's hard to tell without knowing these errors..

But nonetheless, you should avoid setting the component's state outside that component. So, your code'd become:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const blogContent = getBlogContent();

    if (blogContent !== 'error'j this.setBlogs(blogContent);
}

let getBlogContent = () => {
store.set('loaded', false);
return axios.get(ADMIN_URL + '/getAllBlogs')
    .then(response => {
        store.set('loaded', true);
        return response.data.Response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        store.set('loaded', true);
        store.set('errorMessage', error);
        return 'error';
    })
}
```